# browser.visit just a string of html

Tags: zombie.js, headless-browser

With zombie.js,

Is there a way to directly specify the document zombie should visit:

```
browser.visit('<html><head></head><body><body></html>', ...)
```

Eg: not a url, just a string.

I know it supports `file://path/to/my/page.html`, but I just want to feed it with markup directly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zombie's main author answered this question here: https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/314

The answer is: "No."

Answer (score 0):

Zombie can't do it, but the Capsela [browser](http://www.capsela.org/docs/symbols/src/_home_capsela_capsela.org_node_modules_capsela_lib_Browser.js.html) class can - just call loadDocument on an instance of Browser.